# Range issue with ui-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I’m trying to set up a range with a slider. I would prefer if both cursors did not overlap in the same value. In other words, how do I get the sliders to freeze and stay put when the minimum value slider and the maximum value slider come next to each other. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try my answer and accept if it works. Style the outer-fake-slider like the slider and the "usual" slider with border-color and background transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Returning false from the slide function when they're about to collide seems to work: http://jsbin.com/eyoge3/3

Code from the jsbin:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    var oldMin = $("#slider").slider("values", 0);
    var oldMax = $("#slider").slider("values", 1);
    var newMin = ui.values[0];
    var newMax = ui.values[1];

    if( oldMin != newMin && newMin == oldMax )
      return false;
    else if( oldMax != newMax && newMax == oldMin )
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery UI slider range extension

I needed something similar so I've written an extension over existing jQuery UI slider plugin/widget. These are additional options that this extension supports:

- minimum and maximum range size - minimum range size is exactly what you're after
- limiting lower and upper range boundary values - this sets the maximum value for the lower range boundary handle and minimum value for the upper range boundary handle
- automatic range sliding - this allows to drag (any) handle over the limit of maximum range size which in turn drags the other handle along.

You can [get the code on my blog](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/08/advanced-jquery-ui-range-slider.html) (it gets updated so I'm not publishing it here directly).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution to this when doing custom-styled slider yesterday.

Nothing worked from what I found, then I came up with an easy one myself:

1.Put the slider into container div with left and right padding

```
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-main ..."></div>
</div>
```

2.Set the styles of

-container (left and right padding to half slider-handle width) slider

-handle (left-margin to minus half of its width)

Something like this (im writing from memory)

```
<style>
  .slider-container {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
  }
  .slider-handle {
    width: 16px;
    margin-left: -8px;
  }
</style>
```

You should also remove styling from slider-main and move it from there to slider-container